# How to tear down RxJava 2 chain from the middle (and release resources)?

Tags: java, rx-java2, reactivex

What is the recommended way to tear down an RxJava2 chain from the middle, i.e. from an ObservableTransformer?

By tear down I mean

- send `dispose` upstream,
- send `onComplete` downstream, and
- clean up any local resources.

Below is a quick sketch of the setup. Note that it seems to almost work, but `onComplete` is not received downstream.

```
package rx;

import io.reactivex.functions.Function;
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.Emitter;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import io.reactivex.ObservableTransformer;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class StatefulProcessor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Observable<Long> src =
        Observable.interval(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
    Observable<Long> srcExtra =
        Observable.interval(200L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

    Processor proc = new Processor(700L);

    Disposable d =
    src
        .doOnDispose(() -> { System.out.println("Src DISPOSED!"); })
        .compose(proc.process())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .subscribe(x -> { System.out.println("Src: " + x); },
                   e -> { },
                   () -> { System.out.println("Src CONSUMER onComplete()!"); });

    Disposable dExtra =
    srcExtra
        .doOnDispose(() -> { System.out.println("SrcExtra DISPOSED!"); })
        .compose(proc.process())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .subscribe(x -> { System.out.println("SrcExtra: " + x); },
                   e -> { },
                   () -> { System.out.println("SrcExtra CONSUMER onComplete()!"); });

    // pause & destroy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    sleep(2000);
    //d.dispose();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

    sleep(2000);
    proc.release();


    // vait long enough                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    sleep(100000);
}

static void sleep(long millis) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static class Resource {
    Long cnt = null;
    Resource() {}
    void setup(Long l) {
        cnt = l;
        System.out.println("[Processor] setup!");
    }
   Long value() {
        cnt += 1;
        return cnt;
    }
    void teardown() {
        cnt = null;
        System.out.println("[Processor] teardown!");
    }
}

static class Processor {
    private static final CompositeDisposable disp = new CompositeDisposable();
    Resource r = null;

    AtomicBoolean gate = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    Processor(Long x) {
        r = new Resource();
        r.setup(x);
    }
    void release() {
        // cannot release resource yet,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        // there might be an item flying down the chain!                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        // r.teardown(); // <== this throws!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        disp.dispose();
        gate.set(true);
        r.teardown();
    }

    ObservableTransformer<Long, Long> process() {
        return upstream -> {
                return upstream.doOnSubscribe(disp::add).takeUntil((Long __) -> gate.get()).observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).map(__ -> r.value());
            };
        }

    }

}
```

Note that sharing the state/resource across chains is intentional. The output is the following

```
[Processor] setup!
SrcExtra: 701
SrcExtra: 702
SrcExtra: 703
SrcExtra: 704
Src: 705
SrcExtra: 706
SrcExtra: 707
SrcExtra: 708
SrcExtra: 709
SrcExtra: 710
Src: 711
SrcExtra: 712
SrcExtra: 713
SrcExtra: 714
SrcExtra: 715
SrcExtra: 716
Src: 717
SrcExtra: 718
SrcExtra: 719
SrcExtra: 720
SrcExtra: 721
SrcExtra: 722
Src: 723
SrcExtra: 724
SrcExtra DISPOSED!
Src DISPOSED!
[Processor] teardown!
```

Comment: So what's your question of the long code? It run as expect.

Comment: How do I make sure that the downstream part of the chain (below my operator) is released (including any resources it might have acquired). Clearly the upstream is being signaled dispose, but I'm not sure about the downstream.